# Using libraries with GPL license

Tags: gpl

This may be a simple question, but when using libraries that are licensed under GPL, I'm not sure what part of the license applies.

I have two separate libraries in a JAR file that I'm using that I'm distributing with my software. Neither libraries came with a LICENSE file. I modified one of the libraries by removing some of the files from the JAR (examples, tests, etc). My software is also open source but is not licensed.

Is there anything else I need to do to abide by the GPL license of the libraries I'm using?

Comment: @stripies could you be more specific? which specific Jars are you talking about? How do you use them from your own code?  Do you have links, pointers? Also your software **cannot** be open source and not be licensed. Opens source means you have a license. No license means you are granting no rights whatsoever and non can use your code.

Comment: The question may be a duplicate somehow, but my take is that the accepted answer on the duplicate is not correct and misleading. I added my own answer http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/4557/947